# Activate directive in an input from another element - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the following span I have a calendar icon and an input field. However what I am trying to do is to trigger the `jqdatepicker` directive when the user is clicking the calendar icon as well. But if I call the directive in any other element, as expected, it will trigger the calendar to show but when a date is selected the input field will not get updated. Is there any way to solve this?
This is how my html looks like:

```
<span class="input-wrapper">
  <i class="icon calendar"></i>
  <input  data-ng-model="finish" type="text" jqdatepicker data-ng-blur="update()">
</span>
```

**directive:**

```
.directive('jqdatetimepicker', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        element.datetimepicker({
          lang:'de',
          i18n:{
            en:{
               months: [
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
              ],
              dayOfWeek: [
                "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
              ]
             }
          },
          timepicker:true,
          format:'d.m.Y H:i'
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

Comment: Your directive must have `model` to store selected date data. Isn't it?

Comment: yes. I am calling the data-ng-model in my input. sorry I updated it

Comment: Which jqdatepicker directive are you using? Did you create it yourself?

Comment: I added the directive as well :)

Comment: I think you should search for some event while you select date and then fire a function from inside directive or update scope value. and also in directive add require ngmodel true

Answer (score 0):

The reason the field is not updating is because jquery is not synced with angular.

I'm not sure which jquery plugin you're using but usually they expose an `onSelect` event (or something of sort) and you can use it to update the input:

```
//this is pseudo code of course, but the idea would be same for any method
onSelect: function(data){
   scope.finish = data;
   //this is how you tell angular that somthing changed and it needs to run the digest cycle
   scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: tha could be a solution, but the problem is that I have several spans calling the same directive, I cannot change the value in the directive of the datetime.

Comment: you need to create an isolated scope, so only the specific element will change. You do that by adding `scope: {}` to the directive definition